# passing a column name to function in R

Tags: r

One of my problem with R is how to send column name to the function; or generally, how to assign the column name to the object which would be used repeatedly in fuctions.

for instance
this would work:

```
lm(Species~Sepal.Length,data=iris)
```

now I want to replace sepal.Length with Petal.Width or other variable

I would like to do it in this way (assigning the name of column to an object ):

```
x<- "Petal.Width"

lm(Species~x,data=iris)
```

However this returns an error.

or defining the function the takes column name and calculate something like:

```
cal_lm<-function(x){
   lm(Species~x ,data=iris)
}
```

if I use it `cal_lm("Petal.Width")`, it returns error.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think `get` will work: `lm(Species~get(x),data=iris)` but better test

Comment: Try `cal_lm<-function(x){lm(reformulate(x, "Species") ,data=iris)}`